# in table grid format arrange images

Tags: html, css

How to set Properly images in table format see image I would't like to set it in ul li formate. I need it in table formate. (No js use).

demo :https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKXWYDRKTBEP

[image]

Comment: Code is here (https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKXWYDRKTBEP) -thankxx

Comment: Look at colspan and rowspan. It will make it work in single table, thought css grid would me proper way to implement this. Also instead of w3school editor use something like https://codepen.io and put styles there (instead of in html)

Comment: i want use inline css only. if you want use external css than you can do it

Comment: By looking at your code seems like you need to get familiar with "rowspan" and "colspan".

Answer (score 1):

Try This....!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 12px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>Image Grid</h1>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
  <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
  <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```